# Markdown lists under each other

Tags: markdown

```
* foo
* bar
```

produces

```
<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
</ul>
```

and

```
* foo

* bar
```

produces

```
<ul>
  <li><p>foo</p></li>
  <li><p>bar</p></li>
</ul>
```

while I want

```
<ul>
  <li><p>foo</p></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li><p>bar</p></li>
</ul>
```

What's the solution?

Comment: I can't think of a way to coerce Markdown to produce the markup you're trying to get.  Can you use HTML markup in your markdown source file instead of Markdown syntax for this special case?

Answer (score 2):

Since the majority of markdown implementations support the HTML, you can just use the comment between two lists, so it would be the safest and cleanest possible solution for this issue.

Like this:

```
* a

<!-- -->

* b
```

However, that won't give you the `<p>`, so if you'd really need them, you'd need to use the inline HTML here.

```
* <p>a

<!-- -->

* <p>b
```

(in most implementations you won't need to close the `<p>` in markdown — they would be closed automatically by markdown)

Here is a live second example using the stackoverflow's markdown:

- a

- b