# markdown list identation

Tags: markdown

I want to know how to break identation in markdown when using lists.

- List 1

  - list 2

    - list 3

      1. New list

The code used is

```
* List 1
    * List 2
       * List 3
1. New list
```

The issue is that I want 1.New list to be at start of line.

```
* List 1  
   * List 2   
      * List 3
1. New List
```

I know that if I include some text not idented at start of line then the New List Item is place correctly.

---

Example

- List 1

  - list 2

    - list 3

Text in the middle

1. New list

---

but how can I do so with a blank line?

TA

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976324/markdown-lists-under-each-other), probably not elegant but it seems to work.

Any other suggestion?